# ¿Por qué no funciona null con el operador ternario?

Tags: c#, null

Haciendo pruebas...
La siguiente instrucción no compila porque no hay conversión implícita entre `null`.

> CS0173 No se puede determinar el tipo de la expresión condicional porque no hay una conversión implícita entre `'<NULL>'` y `'<NULL>'`

```
string pp = true ? null : null;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El operador ternario necesita determinar el tipo de la expresión condicional. Esto se hace siguiendo los siguientes puntos que aparecen en la [especificación del lenguaje](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions):

> Si `x` tiene tipo `X` y `y` tiene tipo `Y`, a continuación,
>
> - Si una conversión implícita (conversiones implícitas) existe desde `X` a `Y`, pero no desde `Y` a `X`, a continuación, `Y` es el tipo de la expresión condicional.
> - Si una conversión implícita (conversiones implícitas) existe desde `Y` a `X`, pero no desde `X` a `Y`, a continuación, `X` es el tipo de la expresión condicional.
> - En caso contrario, no se puede determinar ningún tipo de expresión y se produce un error de tiempo de compilación.

El problema es que `null` no tiene ningun tipo, asi que como en ninguna de las dos partes de la expresión se puede determinar un tipo, se produce el error.

Para resolverlo, simplemente debes asignar un tipo a cualquiera de las dos expresiones, por ejemplo:

```
string pp = true ? (string)null : null;
```

Comment: Es curioso. Pareciera que en [tag:c#] `null` no tuviera tipo asociado. Yo esperaba que `null` (literal de objeto nulo) tuviese tipo objeto y como tal fuese asignable a otros objetos sin conversión.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster creo recordar que en la primera especificación del lenguaje, `null` tenía un tipo `null` asignado. Pero ya en la segunda o tercera especificación fue eliminado

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215365) tienes una explicación de uno de los programadores del compilador de C#

Comment: Por un lado, tiene sentido que `null` no tenga tipo... por otro lado, en un lenguaje de tipado fuerte ¡no tiene sentido que carezca de tipo! Al final, mi instinto me dice que `<condición> ? null : null` debería dar como resultado `null` lo cuál es sin duda asignable a un objeto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si, parece extraño que `null` no tenga tipo. Pero como dice @EricLipper en su respuesta, tampoco cosas como los métodos anónimos y las expresiones lambda tienen tipo...De todas maneras, no soy experto en compiladores ni entiendo exactamente las consecuencias de tomar una u otra opcion :)